# Why getting NullPointerException when using findBy method of CrudRepository spring-data-dynamodb?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I am using spring boot and spring spring-data-dynamodb.
I am getting NullPointerException when fetching the data from the dynamodb.
Here is my Entity class

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "table1")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private EntId entId;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "hash_key")
    private String hashKey;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "sort_key")
    private String sortKey;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "col1")
    private String col1;

    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = HashMapConverter.class)
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "map")
    private Map<String, List<MetaObject>> metaData;

    //getter and setter
}
```

MetaObject class

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MetaObject {
    private Integer minProductId;
    private Integer maxProductId;
    private String giftId;
    private String streakName;
}
```

this is what is present in the DynamoDb

```
{
 "col1": "no name",
 "hash_key": "123",
 "sort_key": "NOVEMBER",
 "map": "{ 
       "123":[ 
           { 
                "minProductId":1,
                "maxProductId":3,
                "streakName":"sun",
                "giftId":"3"
           },
           { 
                "minProductId":4,
                "maxProductId":10,
                "streakName":"mon",
                "giftId":"2"
           }
       ]
   }"
}
```

I reckon there is some problem with map. Please guide.
My Repository class,

```
@EnableScan
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String> {

   MyEntity findMyEntityByHashKeyAndSortKey(String hashKey, String sortKey);

   MyEntity findMyEntityByEntId(MyEntityId MyEntityId);
}
```

I am using this method findMyEntityByHashKeyAndSortKey to get the Data,

Exception log

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
   at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.getPropertyNameForAccessorMethod(DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.java:346) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
   at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyExtractingEntityMetadataImpl.getRangeKeyPropertyName(DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyExtractingEntityMetadataImpl.java:76) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
   at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBIdIsHashAndRangeKeyEntityInformationImpl.getRangeKeyPropertyName(DynamoDBIdIsHashAndRangeKeyEntityInformationImpl.java:89) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
   at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.DynamoDBEntityWithHashAndRangeKeyCriteria.<init>(DynamoDBEntityWithHashAndRangeKeyCriteria.java:76) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
   at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.create(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.java:71) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
   at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.create(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.java:42) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
   at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.java:56) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
   at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQuery.doCreateQueryWithPermissions(AbstractDynamoDBQuery.java:81) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
```

Why is it giving NullPointerException?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0

Comment: You declared `streakName` as `Integer` in `MetaObject` but it looks like `String` (`"streakName":"sun",`)

Comment: Its my mistake it should be string, but still getting the same error

Comment: can you annotate hash key and range key getters in your entity class with `@DynamoDBHashKey` and `@DynamoDBRangeKey` to see if it works? although its redundant.

Comment: Yeah it worked.... thank you

Comment: @AmitNaik strange fix but thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -> annotate hash key and range key getters in entity class with @DynamoDBHashKey and @DynamoDBRangeKey. Thanks @Amit Naik